Determine the constant $a$ so that the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ax^3-3x^3+8x^2-5x+5}{5x^2-10x+10}$ exists.
The problem:
Determine the constant $a$ so that the limit
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ax^3-3x^3+8x^2-5x+5}{5x^2-10x+10}$$
exists.
The solution:
$a=3$
What I have tried:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ax^3-3x^3+8x^2-5x+5}{5x^2-10x+10}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^3(a-3)+8x^2-5x+5}{5x^2-10x+10}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2(x(a-3)+8-\frac{5}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2})}{x^2(5-\frac{10}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2})}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(a-3)+8-\frac{5}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}}{5-\frac{10}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}$$
My question:
How do I find the constant $a$? Can't it assume all real numbers? Is there a rule for what a limit of a rational function with $x$ approaching $\infty$ must look like for that limit to exist besides the denominator not equaling zero?

It's not clear what "exists" means here.  Looking at the question, I assume they want to exclude $\infty$ as a possible limit.  Thus they would say that $\lim_{x\to \infty}x$ does not exist.   Similarly, something like $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x^2+3}{x+1}$ would not exist. Use that.

I am to find out what $a$ is. How do I do that? What method do I employ?

Read my prior comment.  It explains the issue they are interested in.  MAybe it would help if you just tried various values for $a$.  Does $a=0$ work?  What about $a=1$?  Once you get the idea, this is not difficult.

The method I like to use when we have polynomials, and we are dealing with limits as $ x \rightarrow ∞ $, is to divide both the numerator and the denominator by the highest power of $ x $ present in the denominator, which in this case is $ x^{2} $. Doing so gives us:
$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ \frac{ax^{3}}{x^2} - \frac{3x^3}{x^2} + \frac{8x^2}{x^2} - \frac{5x}{x^2} + \frac{5}{x^2} }{ \frac{5x^2}{x^2} - \frac{10x}{x^2} + \frac{10}{x^2} } $
This simplifies to:
$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ (a-3)x + 8 - \frac{5}{x} + \frac{5}{x^2} }{ 5 - \frac{10}{x} + \frac{10}{x^2} } $
As $ x \rightarrow \infty$, all terms with $ \frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^2} $ will tend to $ 0 $, so the limit becomes:
$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ (a-3)x + 8 }{ 5 } $
For this limit to exist (i.e. for the expression not to tend to infinity), the $ (a - 3)x $ term must vanish, meaning that $ a-3 = 0 \implies a = 3 $.
Thus, $ a = 3 $ is the correct value that makes the limit exist and finite.

As lulu said in the comments, we have to exclude infinity as a possible limit, so the coefficient of $x^3$ must be zero therefore $a=3$.

I see, we do not want the limit to be $\pm \infty$ since it would not exist then. We want the limit to approach an existing number and should therefore eliminate anything in the function that should give something other than that. Right?

You are correct.

In this comment, I suppose you're searching for limit as $x$ goes to $\boldsymbol{+\infty}$. I think what @lulu rightly said is that in the context of your problem, it seems that the existence of a limit excludes the case $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$. In general, we do not exclude infinite limits: we precise in which set the limit can be. Here the limit does exist in $\mathbb R$ if and only if $a=3$, and it always exists in $\overline{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup {\pm\infty}$  (for any value of $a$).

Your work is fine, we reduce to
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(a-3)+8-\frac{5}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}}{5-\frac{10}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}$$
from which we can conclude that

limit is equal to $\infty$ for $a>3$
limit is equal to $\frac 8 5$ for $a=3$
limit is equal to $-\infty$ for $a<3$

therefore, strictly speaking, limit always exists for any value of the parameter $a$ but the limit exists finite if and only if $a=3$.
Refer also to

Limit of sequence exists but might be infinity


Your limit is $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(a-3)x^{3}+8x^{2}-5x+5}{5x^{2}-10x+10}$$
Now a limit when $x\to \infty$ exists only when the degree of both the polynomials in numerator and denominator are same.
For example :
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+c}{dx^{n}+ex^{n-1}+f}$$ for $n\geq 2$ exists and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax^{n+1}+bx^{n}+c}{dx^{n}+ex^{n-1}+f}$$ for $n\geq 2$ will not exist.
Therefore as per your question the co-efficient of $x^{3}$ should be $0$.
Which implies $(a-3)=0$ means that $a=3$.
